# XCUI Test UIScrollView for event that should fire when contentOffset changes

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I'm new to testing and really struggling with how to test our UI logic. Specifically - with testing events that should fire when triggered by the contentOffset change of a UIScrollView.

The main problem I'm facing with testing is that it seems XCUI only allows me to verify UI changes, but the result of the cascade of events I'm trying to test does not perform any UI changes - the result is simply an http call in the background. **Is this possible to test?**

(If needed here is a detailed explanation of my use case:)

When the app launches a tableview is populated with 20 or more cells. As the user scrolls, there is code to detect when each cell is 50% visible or greater. When a cell becomes 50% or more visible for the first time in the tableview, an http call is made. (This is what I'm trying to test but haven't found a way)

Comment: Is there any way to scroll to last row of UITableView using XCUI Test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-user-facing behaviour like network requests being made must be tested by unit tests, not UI tests as UI tests do not have access to anything other than the UI, and it is only a representation of what's on screen (XCUIElements), not the actual UIView objects from your app.

However, the tradeoff here is that unit tests do not test at a very high level and should only test very small scopes of your project, with plenty of mocking/stubbing.

My recommendation here is to use a combination of both unit and UI tests. Use a unit test to check that the network call is made at the right point and a UI test to test that the app launches and that the cells display the right content when scrolled. For the UI test, you could stub the response from the server to ensure that you always get valid data using a stubbing framework like OHHTTPStubs. Together, these two types of tests would be able to test what you want.

Comment: Thank you! Not the answer I wanted to hear (would be nice if UITest could have some way to talk with underlying components), but it seems the right answer none the less.

Comment: Question, you said "Use a unit test to check that the network call is made at the right point". However the network call is made based on events from UI elements (specifically, when a view becomes visible in scrollview frame) How would I test this using only unit tests?

Comment: I can’t give a good answer to that without access to your codebase, but unit tests should not have much integration testing so you should probably have one test testing that the method which makes the network call exhibits the proper behaviour, where the test just calls the method and possibly observes a stub network object, and another test testing that when the view is 50% visible, its view is populated with content. For the second test, you might want to have a stub object which immediately returns some static data for populating the view, rather than the real object.